# how to protect Google Chrome 80 beta asp + iframe

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8.5, samesite

The web service environment is operated by Windows 2012 server, IIS8.5, Classic asp.

this is problem about Chrome 80ver SameSite Issue.

On our site, we make payments by calling iframes and receive the results by returnurl.
However, there is a problem in returnurl that changes the existing session value (sometimes it is maintained and sometimes it is changed).

I tried to 
First.  Add header in source code as follows

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "SameSite=None; Secur; path=/; HttpOnly"
```

Second. Add web.config

```
<system.web>
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None" />
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
```

Third.  Add web.config rewrite

```
<rewrite>
 <outboundRules>
    <rule name="AddSameSiteCookieFlag">
       <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^(.*SessionID)(SameSite=Lax)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1};SameSite=None" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Is there a way to set the samesite setting to none in IIS8.5?

Comment: Can you use Chrome DevTools to check what value is actually being returned on your `Set-Cookie` headers? There's a typo in your first example, `Secur` is missing an `e`. It's also not clear where you are adding the `Response.AddHeader` call, it doesn't make any sense on its own as you're not specifying an actual cookie name and value.

Comment: **Microsoft ASP.NET will now emit a SameSite cookie header when HttpCookie.SameSite value is "None" to accommodate upcoming changes to SameSite cookie handling in Chrome. As part of this change, FormsAuth and SessionState cookies will also be issued with SameSite = 'Lax' instead of the previous default of 'None', though these values can be overridden in web.config**
You have to set the cookieSameSite= "None" in the session state tag to avoid this issue. `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None"  cookieless="false" timeout="360"> 
</sessionState>`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal might be helpful but not ASP.Net. OP is using Classic ASP with IIS 8.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm running the exact configuration mentioned in this question and found the following web.config rewrite rules to work as a *baseline* solution:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
            <conditions>
        </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None; Secure" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
            </preCondition>
            <preCondition name="No SameSite">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None; Secure" negate="true" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```